# Is there a path finding solution for dynamic maps?

Tags: scripting, game-engine

I need a reliable method for path finding characters in my rts-like game, but there seems to be no solution at all if there isn't a fixed nav-mesh... How can I make my characters move around newly generated buildings in the game? I can't find any sample scripts anywhere :/
I do not want to use the steering or path-following actuators, as their behaviour seems way too unreliable to me.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link, it helps me a lot understanding the mistery of path finding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have some programming skill, patfinding with random maps or evolving maps is possible but not easy.

[Here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?347409-RTS-game-tools-experiements) is my Blender artists thread with experiments on patfinding with random terrain (as well as other RTS topics).

As an RTS usually takes place on a 2D landscape you can use quite simple pathfinding techniques. I got data from a mesh to use as obstacles and then used mathutils.geometry functions to help generate a graph of connections between random points. In this case instead of a walk mesh, I generated an no-walk mesh and used it to cull a graph of connected points.

If your maps are fixed, but they are evolving, like with player placed buildings, you can just make the buildings in to obstacles.